# How to set session domain on the fly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way in Rails to set domain specific sessions without manually declaring `action_controller.session[:domain]`?

For instance:

```
class SomeController
  def login
    session[:logged_in] = true #this goes to the default domain: app.com

    session[:user_id] = @user.id #this goes to: customerA.app.com
  end
end
```

Is this possible without regular cookies?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://excid3.com/blog/sharing-a-devise-user-session-across-subdomains-with-rails-3/